# SSJS to delete rows from a data extension via a lookup table

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

Is there a way to delete selected rows from a Data extension(MASTER_DE) by looking up another data extension as a lookup (to identify the subscriber keys that need to be deleted) using SSJS?

I have found some blogs to delete all the data but not selected rows.

Basically, I have a client who doesn't have data retention policy applied to DE's and you can't add data retention policy once it's created. so I was trying to create a way to delete any records that are older than 3 months through an automation.

Answer (score 5):

Good news! You CAN actually change the data retention properties on an existing DE.

You just need to create an Update SOAP API call to the [DataExtensio](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm)n Object and use the DataRententionPeriod, DataRetentionLength and DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod properties.

As far as your requested use case, you can easily do that as well using something like below.

```
<script runat="server">

     var masterDE = DataExtension.Init("MASTER_DE");
     var filter = {Property:"Date",SimpleOperator:"greaterThan",Value: yourDate};
     var data = masterDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);

     for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

       var subKey = data[i].SubscriberKey;

       var rowDelete = Platform.Function.DeleteData('MASTER_DE',['SubscriberKey'],[subKey]);

    };
</script>
```

---

Based on your comments, it seems you are going to store all the items that need deletion in another DE.  In that case it is even easier:

```
<script runat="server">

     var deleteDE = DataExtension.Init("yourDELETE_DE");
     var data = deleteDE.Rows.Retrieve();

     for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

       var subKey = data[i].SubscriberKey;

       var rowDelete = Platform.Function.DeleteData('MASTER_DE',['SubscriberKey'],[subKey]);

    };
</script>
```

Comment: what if I want to use another DE as a lookup? I was thinking all the subscriber keys in the lookup needs deleting and only delete the matching records from the MASTER_DE

Comment: @PeterHo see answer edits above

Comment: just tried this and it keeps failing but not getting any errors in automation studio                                                                            
 <script runat="server">

     var deleteDE = DataExtension.Init("PH_TEST_DE");//DE to delete from
     var data = deleteDE.Rows.Retrieve();

     for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

       var subKey = data[i].SubscriberKey;

       var rowDelete = Platform.Function.DeleteData('PH_SubscribersToDelete',['SubscriberKey'],[subKey]); // Look up DE

    };
</script>

Comment: does it run without errors but subkeys not deleted, or does it error but you do not see any error messages in AS?

Comment: It just errors in AS without any errors so it doesnt delete anything

Comment: Try putting it into a Cloud page / microsite with a Try/Catch to hopefully gather error data. I also would try changing `data[i].SubscriberKey` to `data[i]["SubscriberKey"]`

Comment: The detail that caused me some frustration is that DataExtension.Init() expects the data extension *external key*, while the first parameter of DeleteData() expects the data extension *name*.

Comment: @Chris, that is why I usually recommend using the same value for both external key and name. It helps to make inconsistencies like that in the platform less impactful.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core", "1");

     var deleteDE = DataExtension.Init("yourDELETE_DE External Key");
     var data = deleteDE.Rows.Retrieve();

     for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

       var subKey = data[i].SubscriberKey;

       var rowDelete = Platform.Function.DeleteData('MASTER_DE',['SubscriberKey'],[subKey]);

    };
</script>
```

the above code works fine. We need to add `Platform.Load("Core", "1");` and delete DE external key as mentioned in above code.